# What's wrong with this UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-update

I need a SQL query to run

```
UPDATE function
SET active = 0
WHERE unitRef IN
    (SELECT unitRef 
       FROM project_unit 
      WHERE projectRef = 1);
```

When I run this query, phpmyadmin says that 0 rows are affected. 
However when I run following code standalone:

```
SELECT unitRef 
  FROM project_unit 
 WHERE projectRef = 1
```

it returns me more than 1 row.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `update function set active=0...`?

Answer (score 3):

The two constructs aren't equivalent. Instead, try this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM function
 WHERE unitRef in
    (select 
    unitRef 
    from project_unit 
    where projectRef=1);
```

Comment: @DonkeyKong: this is the query that must return you some data.  Replace the 'UPDATE Table SET ...' with 'SELECT * FROM Table' to see which rows would be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'SET' keyword...

```
UPDATE `function`
SET active = 0
WHERE unitRef IN (SELECT unitRef FROM project_unit WHERE projectRef = 1);
```

Although that would have given you an error, not just said `0 row(s) affected`. Do the values returned by the subquery exist in the field `unitRef` for the table `function`?

Comment: yes that column exists. I've edited the question. I've forgot to type set keyword only in question. That's why it haven't given me an error..

Comment: Sorry - that was worded poorly. Do the values returned by the subquery exist in the field `unitRef` for the table `function`, is what I should have said.

Answer (score 0):

for MS SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [function]
SET active=0
WHERE unitRef in
    (SELECT
    pu.unitRef 
    FROM project_unit as pu
    WHERE pu.projectRef=1);
```